# Drawing rectangular grid using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Is there an easy way in python using pyplot (matplotlib) to create a rectangular grid (like this, but perhaps gridded) like this:
[image]

I am pretty new to python, and there may be a simple solution to this, but I have been unable to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly which details you're going for but here's a start...

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.set_xticks(range(-5, 6))
ax.set_yticks(range(-5, 6))
ax.set_xlim((-5.5, 5.5))
ax.set_ylim((-5.5, 5.5))
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, that's great. I just needed an example to point me in the right direction. Thanks!